# No line break from textarea in php mail

Tags: post, php

As you can see from the code, the user first enter name and message and click send.
The problem is the text area. When i make line breaks, there still isn't any line breaks in the e-mail i get.

```
<?php
$to = "abc@xyz.com";
$subject = "Message from contact form";

//begin of HTML message
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body>
<b>Name:</b><br>
{$_POST['name']}
<br>
<b>Message:</b><br>
{$_POST['message']}
</body>
</html>
EOF;
//end of message

$header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$header .= "from:abc@xyz.com";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
echo "Email sent!";
?>

<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="name" style="width: 200px;"> <br><br>

Message: <br>
<textarea name="message" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></textarea> <br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($message)` before your `mail()` call and paste the output

Comment: Try to do `nl2br($_POST['message'])`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's how HTML is meant to be. No matter how many times you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in your HTML source, the browser will only show line feeds when there's an HTML tag that tells it to do so.

You can insert such tags with [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/nl2br). You also want to escape your raw input with [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));

//begin of HTML message
$message = <<<EOF
<html>
<body>
<b>Name:</b><br>
{$name}
<br>
<b>Message:</b><br>
{$message}
</body>
</html>
EOF;
```

Comment: where do you want me to put nl2br() tag?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:-

```
echo nl2br("My name is\n user2232809");
```

will output

My name is
 user2232809

This function returns string with `<br /> or <br>` inserted before all newlines. So when you press enter it returns it's html equivalent `<br>`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's nl2br() on the textarea's text....

Comment: where do you want me to put nl2br() tag?

Comment: $tempMsg = nl2br($_POST['message']);  <b>Message:</b><br>{$tempMsg}

Comment: Sorry, I am new here ... will keep this in mind next time..